# How to redirect old PHP scripts in NGINX configuration to a new HTTPS site?

Tags: nginx, php, https, regex

I have a problem, I'm trying to catch all PHP scripts except one in my NGINX configuration for my HTTP domain configuration:

I have a general rule for all PHP files

```
    location ~ \.php$ {

    include fastcgi_params;

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.$user.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass php7-fpm-sock;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}
```

But I need to handle old PHP script from the old site to redirect to a HTTPS link (with a different structure).

I have tried to put this in PHP handler, in **location / {}** block, in **location /download {}** block, but it all fails and the default trigger is pulled on this script (404 in PHP handler)

```
    rewrite ^/download\.php\?file_id=(.*)$ https://$server_name/download/id/$1 permanent;
```

How to handle it properly? Where to put this exception in NGINX configuration to make it work? What am I doing wrong?

PS. I need to keep a separate HTTP config for other things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. The order of operations is important, it's well explained at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846238/guide-on-how-to-use-regex-in-nginx-location-block-section

And the solution looks like this:

```
location ^~ /download.php {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name/download/id/$arg_file_id permanent;
}
```